# How can I access config variables in Node.js app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js app built in Angular which involves a call to the GitHub API. I have my personal access token in a secrets.js file which is in my .gitignore file so the app works on my local machine. I've deployed the app to Heroku and set a config variable called `GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN` but can't work out how to reference this config variable from within the search factory I made in the Angular app.

Here is the code from my search factory:

```
readmeSearch.factory('RepoSearch', ['$http', function($http) {

  return {
    query: function(searchTerm) {
      return $http({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + searchTerm + '/repos',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          'access_token': gitAccessToken
        }
      });
    }
  };

}]);
```

where the variable gitAccessToken is defined in my secrets.js file. I know that the config variable can be referenced in the node app by `process.env.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN` but I'm not sure how to pass this to the search factory. Or should this be approached in a different way? If I write

```
'access_token': process.env.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN || gitAccessToken
```

I get a

> Reference Error: process not defined

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is **server** started ? Is your application in *running* state ?

Comment: hi @RayonDabre i'm not quite sure what you mean. I can run `node server.js` and visit `localhost:3000` and it all works fine. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Where do you find this error ? In your local environment or while running it over Heroku ?

Comment: Perhaps the Angular code executes in browser while the environment variable is set on the server ? There is no `process` global on the browser side.

Comment: Both local and on Heroku @RayonDabre

Comment: Try `Process.env.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: Hi @S.D. yes I thought it might be something along those lines. Do you have any hints for how I could pass the config variable from the server to the browser?